# SQL query to select data from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables i.e.

**Invitation**

- InvitationID
- UserID
- Email

**Users**

- UserID
- Username

I have data in both table

**Invitation** table data

```
29  NULL    test1@example.com   
40  8       test2@example.com                                                                       
41  8       test3@example.com
```

**Users** table data

```
8     someone@example.com
```

Now I want to select all data from the `Invitation` table, and also want to select `Username` from `Users` table where `Invitation.InvitationID` is equal to `Users.UserID`.

I use this following query to select data

```
SELECT 
    Invitations.*, Users.UserName
FROM
    Invitations 
INNER JOIN
    Users ON Invitations.UserID = Users.UserID
```

But it returns only two rows. I want to select all rows from the `Invitation` table. If `Invitation.UserID` is `null` then `Username` is also `null`. I want output like this:

```
 29  NULL   test1@example.com   Null
 40  8      test2@example.com   someone@example.com                                                                  
 41  8      test3@example.com   someone@example.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use left join :

```
SELECT Invitations.*, Users.UserName
FROM     Invitations left JOIN
              Users ON Invitations.UserID = Users.UserID
```